# Password validation by using java script regular expression contains at least two digit anywhere. It can contain special characters and letters

Tags: javascript

I need to check for password by using java script regular expression. for the password check, it should have at least two digit, it can contain special character, it has letters as well.

Comment: I enjoy using https://www.debuggex.com/ for any regex debugging.

Comment: I am trying in https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following script should do the trick. If you're going to use this script, you'll need a button that calls the function with the inputted password as its argument. I hope this helps.

```
var password;   
var passValid = false;

function checkPass(enteredPass) {
    if(enteredPass.length >= 2) { //Makes sure that the entered password is equal to or higher than the minimum length
        var numsFound = 0;
        var letterFound = false;
        var splitPass = enteredPass.split("");
        for(i=0; i < enteredPass.length; i++) { //Checks all characters for letters and numbers
            if(splitPass[i] >= 0 && splitPass[i] <= 9) {
                numsFound++;                       
            } else if(splitPass[i] >= "a" && splitPass[i] <= "z" || splitPass[i] >= "A" && splitPass[i] <= "Z") {
                letterFound = true;                             
            };
            if(numsFound >= 2 && letterFound) { //Successful scenario
                password = enteredPass;
                console.log("the entered password is valid, updated password successfully");
                return;
            };
        };
    };
    console.log("the entered password is invalid, update cancelled"); //Error scenario
};
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I will try to use your script in case the regular expression I found fails at any scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have framed regular expression, which should check for alphanumeric along with set of special characters and find at least 2 digits.

```
\(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){2,})[a-zA-Z0-9!@$*\-.\/?_&,]{1,}\
```

I took the help of https://regex101.com site for reference & testing.